# Model method returning everything in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, model, return

I want my method to only return the number of followers. I find that if it doesn't progress to the last 'if' statement it just returns the query or the hash from the previous code.

```
def my_twitter_followers
    if JSON.parse(contact_hash)["social_profiles"]
        JSON.parse(contact_hash)["social_profiles"].each do |profile|
            if profile["followers"] 
                return profile["followers"]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I want it to return followers if the Twitter profile exists within the social_profiles array that contains a hash (hence why the following ["followers"]

> [{"url"=>"http://gravatar.com/xxxxxx", "id"=>"xxxxxx", "type"=>"gravatar", "type_id"=>"gravatar", "type_name"=>"Gravatar", "username"=>"xxxxxxx", "bio"=>"SOME LARGE BIO"}, {"url"=>"http://www.facebook.com/xxxxxxx", "type"=>"facebook", "type_id"=>"facebook", "type_name"=>"Facebook", "username"=>"xxxxxx", "id"=>"xxxxxx"}, {"url"=>"http://www.quora.com/xxxxxxx", "type"=>"quora", "username"=>"xxxxxx", "type_id"=>"quora", "type_name"=>"Quora"}, {"url"=>"http://twitter.com/xxxxxxx", "type"=>"twitter", "username"=>"xxxxx", "type_id"=>"twitter", "followers" => "1000" "type_name"=>"Twitter"}, {"url"=>"http://plancast.com/user/xxxxxx", "id"=>"xxxxxx", "type"=>"plancast", "type_id"=>"plancast", "type_name"=>"Plancast"}, {"url"=>"http://youtube.com/user/xxxxxxx", "type"=>"youtube", "username"=>"xxxxxx", "type_id"=>"youtube", "type_name"=>"Youtube"}]

Thanks!

Comment: Ruby returns the last executed result as the result of the calling of a method. What do you want it to return if there are no followers?

Comment: I want it to return 0 or a string. How can I make it do that?

Comment: I dont understand something. Why are you having a `return` within a `each` block? I understand from your code that you may have multiple social profiles and each has a set of followers. And  you want all those followers. But the current code, (or what you are doing) will return the first set of followers found only

Comment: To clarify, I find multiple social profiles. I want to select the twitter one and find the followers. An example:

Comment: I will edit the question to display more code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work. If I actually understand what you are asking for.

```
def my_twitter_followers
    if JSON.parse(contact_hash)["social_profiles"]
        JSON.parse(contact_hash)["social_profiles"].each do |profile|
            if profile["type"] == "twitter" 
                return profile["followers"] unless profile["followers"].blank?
            end
        end
    end
    return 0
end
```

In this case, if there is a twitter profile. It will return the twitter followers, unless the there are no followers. In which case it will return 0 (zero)

Comment: that works great! My only problem is that some profiles don't have Twitter and return the array containing the remaining social profiles.

Comment: Worked beautifully! Thanks so much!

Comment: Question out of curiosity. Why was the return 0 placed within the first 'if' statement and not within the 'each' block?

Comment: Because, it will test the first social_profile and if its the type is not "twitter", it will immediately return 0 (not checking the other profiles). But, now that you said that. I think the return 0 should be after the first if statement. Anyway, hope it helped. Mark answer as right if you can :)